# Why and how often do AI Empires change their names?

Tags: stellaris

I often see the AI change the names of their Empires over a course of a game but I don't see a change in their ethics<sup>[1]</sup>. Like from "Interstellar Zaxxoid Alliance" to "Polity of Oxx-Oxx". That begs the question, why and how often do these name change?

---

<sup>[1] Usually, you would get an event pop-up when that happens.</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't give a lot of information to work with, but I'll enumerate the possibilities I've seen so far:

- Change in [Government](https://stellaris.paradoxwikis.com/Government), which can be instigated by changes in Authority, Ethics, or Civics. ( I know you've ruled out ethics changes, but  policy changes should be irrelevant.)

  - [Ethics](https://stellaris.paradoxwikis.com/Ethos) changes are made by embracing the related [Faction](https://stellaris.paradoxwikis.com/Factions) in the empire.
  - Authority and Civic changes are enacted at a cost of 250 influence. See the "Reform Government" button to do this in your own empire.  Authority changes can be used to appease Authoritarian or Egalitarian factions and are far more likely to result in a change of Government than the other two factors.
- An empire splits due to [Rebellion](https://stellaris.paradoxwikis.com/Unrest) (generally a single planet) or [Liberation](https://stellaris.paradoxwikis.com/Warfare#Liberation) (generally a handful of planets).  The new state gets a new name, often similar to the parent state's.

  - Rebel States often subjugate themselves to alternative (preferably Egalitarian) overlords (only to be integrated 10 years later).
  - Liberated States embrace the Ethics of their Liberators, are very likely to ally themselves to their Liberators, and are likely to last longer.

  In either case the parent state still suffers from the same internal/external pressures that created the original split, and may not survive long.

Comment: Sorry for the slight confusion. Forget that I mentioned policy. I think ethics changes occurs very rarely and the name changes usually usually take place when a civic is changes/added/removed, it's they who determine the overall description of an Empire's government after the government type and ethics.